# Parsing error: missing semicolon on render()

Tags: reactjs

I am currently following a ReactJS tutorial and got an parsing error where the render is missing a semicolon. I can't find any missing curly braces or anything regarding this missing semicolon error and I don't think that render even needs a semicolon. Here's the code, please guide me in fixing this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import io from 'socket.io-client'

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.localVideoref = React.createRef()
    this.remoteVideoref = React.createRef()

    this.socket = null
  }

  componentDidMount = () =>{
    this.socket = io(
      '/webrtcPeer',
      {
        path: '/webrtc',
        query: {}
      }
    )

    this.socket.on('connection-success', success => {
      console.log(success)
    })

    this.socket.on('offerOrAnswer', (sdp) => {
      this.textref.value = JSON.stringify(sdp)

      this.pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp))
    })

    this.socket.on('candidate', (candidate) => {
      this.pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate))
    })

    const pc_config = {
      "iceServers": [
        {
          urls : 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
        }
      ]
    }

    this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config)

    this.pc.onicecandidate = (e) => {
      if (e.candidate) {
        this.sendToPeer('candidate', e.candidate)
    }

    this.pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = (e) => {
      console.log(e)
    }

    this.pc.onaddstream = (e) => {
      this.remoteVideoref.current.srcObject = e.stream
    }

    const constraints = {
      video: true,
      audio: false
    }

    const success = (stream) => {
      window.localStream = stream
      this.localVideoref.current.srcObject = stream
      this.pc.addStream(stream)
    }

    const failure = (e) => {
      console.log('getUserMedia Error: ', e)
    }

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(success)
    .catch(failure)
  }

  createOffer = () => {
    console.log('Offer')
    this.pc.createOffer({offerToReceiveVideo: 1})
    .then(sdp => {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp))
      this.pc.setLocalDescription(sdp)
      this.sendToPeer('offerOrAnswer', sdp)
    })
  }
  
  setRemoteDescription = () => {
    const desc = JSON.parse(this.textref.value)

    this.pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(desc))
  }

  createAnswer = () => {
    console.log('Answer')
    this.pc.createAnswer({offerToReceiveVideo: 1})
    .then(sdp => {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp))
      this.pc.setLocalDescription(sdp)
      this.sendToPeer('offerOrAnswer', sdp)
    }, e => {})
  }

  addCandidate = () => {
    this.candidate.forEach(candidate => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(candidate))
      this.pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate))
    })
  }
  
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <video
        style={{
          width: 240,
          height: 240,
          margin: 5,
          backgroundColor: 'black'
        }}
        ref={ this.localVideoref }
        autoPlay>
      </video>
      <video
        style={{
          width: 240,
          height: 240,
          margin: 5,
          backgroundColor: 'black'
        }}
        ref={ this.remoteVideoref }
        autoPlay>
      </video>
      <br />

      <button onClick={this.createOffer}>Offer</button>
      <button onClick={this.createAnswer}>Answer</button>

      <br />
      <textarea style={{ width: 450, height:40 }} ref={ref => { this.textref = ref }} />
    </div>
    )}
  }
}  

export default App
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this message because you have a syntax error in your code.
There is a missing a curly bracket in your definition of `this.pc.onicecandidate`, it should be:

```
this.pc.onicecandidate = (e) => {
  if (e.candidate) {
    this.sendToPeer('candidate', e.candidate)
  } // <-- this was missing
}
```

You have also added an extra curly at the end:

```
    ...
    </div>
    )}
  } // <-- remove me
}  

export default App
```

Comment: As a side note, it is easier to spot these types of errors if you indent consistently.  In particular, `render()` should ideally be indented to match the other methods.